# DC motor as a generator

Tags: led, motor, dc, generator

I was wondering if I could use a simple DC motor to power a small LED and how fast I would need to spin it to do so.

I am making a small air-powered engine in school and I kind of want to connect it to a small DC motor to power a LED just to show it is producing power. I am not sure what I will need to do so, or even if it is possible, so I wanted to ask here. I will calculate how many kW the engine is producing and post it here.

Comment: do you have the DC motor and the LED? ... do an experiment

Comment: `on wednesday i will calculate how many kw the engine is producing and post it here` ... why? ... this is a Q&A site ... it is not a forum

Comment: A small 2V red LED is bright at 20mA. Then the power it uses is 2V x 0.02A= 0.04W.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but note that a motor creating electrical power is more difficult to turn than a motor with the leads disconnected.  Make sure your air motor can turn the motor when the leads are connected to a resistor (to limit current) and LED in series.

You'll be able to get to 2 to 3 volts required for the LED at much lower RPM with a 12v motor than the high speed required if you try to do it with a 1.5 or 3v motor.

Answer (score 0):

An unloaded DC motor with a certain applied voltage will generate a back emf that is about 90 % of the applied voltage. A (red) LED requires about 1.7 V to start to light. So, if you apply 2 V to the motor, it will (internally) generate about 1.6 V -- nearly enough to light the LED. If you manually rotate it, you would need to reach that speed (rpm).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate enough power with a small, permanent-magnet DC motor to light an LED. The motor needs to spin fast enough to produce a bit more that 2 volts. The required speed will be pretty close to the speed that the motor operates when a bit more than 2 volts is used to power the motor. If you know the rated voltage and RPM of the motor, divided the voltage by the RPM to get the volts per RPM. A small wind turbine may be capable of burning out the LED. Connecting a 100 to 300 ohm resistor in series would probably be enough to prevent that. Try it by rotating the turbine by hand. Connect the LED both ways to determine which connection is the proper polarity for the motor rotation direction.